# T-SQL subselect statement is returning all rows instead of limiting to 1 based on subselect

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to return just the first row where the BLOCK_STOP_ORDER = 2.  What is wrong with my SQL?  Why isn't WHERE SCHEDULE.BLOCK_STOP_ORDER = (SELECT MIN(S1.BLOCK_STOP_ORDER....
working?  When I run the subselect on its own it returns the value '2' - doesn't that mean it should then limit the query result to only the row(s) where BLOCK_STOP_ORDER = 2?

```
SELECT      ROUTE.ROUTE_ABBR, SCHEDULE.ROUTE_DIRECTION_ID, SCHEDULE.PATTERN_ID, SCHEDULE.BLOCK_STOP_ORDER,
            SCHEDULE.SCHEDULED_TIME, GEO_NODE.GEO_NODE_ABBR, TRIP.TRIP_SEQUENCE AS TPST  
FROM        SCHEDULE 
 INNER JOIN GEO_NODE ON SCHEDULE.GEO_NODE_ID = GEO_NODE.GEO_NODE_ID
 INNER JOIN ROUTE    ON SCHEDULE.ROUTE_ID = ROUTE.ROUTE_ID 
 INNER JOIN TRIP     ON SCHEDULE.TRIP_ID = TRIP.TRIP_ID 
WHERE     (SCHEDULE.CALENDAR_ID = '120221024') AND ROUTE.ROUTE_ABBR = '001' 
    AND  SCHEDULE.ROUTE_DIRECTION_ID = '2'  AND SCHEDULE.PATTERN_ID = '270082'
    AND TRIP.TRIP_SEQUENCE = '18600' 

    AND SCHEDULE.BLOCK_STOP_ORDER =
      (SELECT MIN(S1.BLOCK_STOP_ORDER) 
        FROM SCHEDULE S1 
        WHERE SCHEDULE.CALENDAR_ID = S1.CALENDAR_ID 
           AND SCHEDULE.ROUTE_ID = S1.ROUTE_ID 
           AND SCHEDULE.ROUTE_DIRECTION_ID = S1.ROUTE_DIRECTION_ID 
           AND SCHEDULE.PATTERN_ID = S1.PATTERN_ID 
           AND SCHEDULE.SCHEDULED_TIME = S1.SCHEDULED_TIME  
           AND SCHEDULE.GEO_NODE_ID = S1.GEO_NODE_ID  
           AND SCHEDULE.BLOCK_STOP_ORDER = S1.BLOCK_STOP_ORDER 
           AND SCHEDULE.TRIP_ID = S1.TRIP_ID
        )
 
GROUP BY  ROUTE.ROUTE_ABBR, SCHEDULE.ROUTE_DIRECTION_ID,
    SCHEDULE.PATTERN_ID, SCHEDULE.SCHEDULED_TIME, 
    GEO_NODE.GEO_NODE_ABBR, SCHEDULE.BLOCK_STOP_ORDER, TRIP.TRIP_SEQUENCE 

ORDER BY ROUTE.ROUTE_ABBR, SCHEDULE.ROUTE_DIRECTION_ID, TRIP.TRIP_SEQUENCE
```

Results:

| ROUTE_ABBR | ROUTE_DIRECTION_ID | PATTERN_ID | BLOCK_STOP_ORDER | SCHEDULED_TIME | GEO_NODE_ABBR | TPST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2 | 270082 | 2 | 18600 | 1251 | 18600 |
| 001 | 2 | 270082 | 3 | 18600 | 1346 | 18600 |
| 001 | 2 | 270082 | 5 | 18720 | 1123 | 18600 |
| 001 | 2 | 270082 | 6 | 18720 | 11372 | 18600 |
| 001 | 2 | 270082 | 4 | 18720 | 1570 | 18600 |
| 001 | 2 | 270082 | 8 | 18780 | 11373 | 18600 |

Comment: Please don't quote your query and results...

Comment: Are the results you are showing the results you are getting or the results you want? Either way, please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: My best guess is you'll find a `ROW_NUMBER()` solution much clearer than a `SELECT MIN()...` query.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably better solved with the [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) windowing function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT r.ROUTE_ABBR, s.ROUTE_DIRECTION_ID, s.PATTERN_ID, s.BLOCK_STOP_ORDER,
           s.SCHEDULED_TIME, g.GEO_NODE_ABBR, t.TRIP_SEQUENCE AS TPST,
           row_number() over (order by SCHEDULE.BLOCK_STOP_ORDER) rn
    FROM        SCHEDULE s 
     INNER JOIN GEO_NODE g ON s.GEO_NODE_ID = g.GEO_NODE_ID
     INNER JOIN ROUTE    r ON s.ROUTE_ID = r.ROUTE_ID 
     INNER JOIN TRIP     t ON s.TRIP_ID = t.TRIP_ID 

    WHERE     s.CALENDAR_ID = '120221024' AND r.ROUTE_ABBR = '001' 
        AND   s.ROUTE_DIRECTION_ID = '2'  AND s.PATTERN_ID = '270082'
        AND   t.TRIP_SEQUENCE = '18600' 
) t1
WHERE rn=1
ORDER BY t1.ROUTE_ABBR, t1.ROUTE_DIRECTION_ID, t1.TRIP_SEQUENCE
```

The problem with the original is the name `SCHEDULE`. For the full version of the query, the subquery is matching the name in the nested select with the instance of the table from the outer select. This correlates the results of the inner table with the outer, so only the item from that row of the outer table is eligible.

When you run the inner query by itself, separate from the outer query, there is only the one instance of the table. In that situation the WHERE conditions are matching the table to itself — they are **always true** — and you just get the smallest value of all the rows: `2`.

This is why you should **ALWAYS** give **ALL** the tables in your queries an alias, and **ONLY** reference them by that alias (as I did in my answer). Do this, and the `MIN()` version can work... but will still be slower and more code than using `row_number()`.

Finally, the use of `DISTINCT` / `GROUP BY` with *every* `SELECT` column is usually an indicator you don't fully understand the `JOIN` relationships used in the query, and in at least one case the join conditions are not sufficiently selective. I'd hesitate to move a query like that to production, even if it seems to be working, though I confess most of us have done it at some point anyway.